# page expired message in php script

Tags: php

i am working on  an e-commerce website using php.
i have tried post/get and now session but problem is persisting.
when i hit back button it display message page has expired. i thought may be i am not handlling session variables proparly but i dont know what to do ?
what could be cause ans what could be solution .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably seeing the form submission "page is expired" page. If you're submitting forms and you attempt to back up, that page is expired, you have to resubmit the form data to view the page again. Just refresh the page.

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/183763

Comment: is not there any solution except refreshing the page again n
 again :(   ?

Comment: I believe this is a client side setting. **You** may be able to get around it, but it will still happen to your guests. It's for privacy/protection/security. That way you don't go back and order two `Rick Astley - It Would Take a Strong Man` mint condition Vinyls.